# Why they auto change "<" to &lt;

Tags: php, auto

Im generate XML file, in title tags i change value and add specialchars like "<" but when i generate xml they change this auto in "< and >"

i try:

```
htmlspecialchars
```

and

```
htmlspecialchars_decode
```

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('p.xml');
$i = 0;
$tytuly = $dom->getElementsByTagName('auction_title');

foreach ($tytuly as $tytul){

$title = $tytul->nodeValue;
$tytul->nodeValue = htmlspecialchars_decode("<![CDATA[").doTitleCut($title).htmlspecialchars_decode("]]>");
$i = $i+1;

}

$dom->save("4.xml");
```

XML:

```
&lt;![CDATA[Airontek gniazdo e40 do żarówek CFL - kabel 2m]]&gt;
```

I wana know why they change this auto even if i use htmlspecialchars?

I just wana have:

```
<[CDATA[Airontek gniazdo e40 do żarówek CFL - kabel 2m]]>
```

Comment: Absolutely impossible to tell what you are even doing, when you just show such lines of code without any context or the slightest explanation. Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: `htmlspecialchars_decodes` should be `htmlspecialchars_decode`, then it seems to work fine https://3v4l.org/2jUtO

Comment: Are you using DOMDocument or simply creating a string?

Comment: `nodeValue` is the _text content_ of the element, and the DOMDocument library automatically replaces < and > with their named entities when you use this to insert _text_. If you want to create a CDATA section, then do that using the appropriate method, and append it to the element where you want it. https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php

Comment: (Whether this _needs_ a CDATA section, would be a different question. Text such as `Airontek gniazdo e40 do żarówek CFL - kabel 2m` could simply be inserted as that - _text_ - to begin with.)